# staleElementReferenceException in ExpectedConditions -->elementToBeClickable

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Just wondering ,if  there is scope of `StaleElementReferenceException` in

`WebDriver ExpectedConditions-->elementToBeClickable(WebElement element)`

Checking the source code of the function ,`StaleElementReferenceException` is  in catch and returns null. 
But there is  line of code in method `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable`. which is throwing this exception at random time(currently not having any concrete test to display)

```
public ExpectedCondition<WebElement> visibilityOfElement =
      ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element);
```

and if we check above code there is no catching of `StaleElementException`

Can some please help in understanding if there is possibility of `staleElementException` in the above mentioned method? if yes - is this known issue? Any work around to prevent random failures?

Thanks
Kapil Aggarwal

Comment: You can always catch the stale element exception. Within the catch block you can perform the same action once again that you had intended to perform. So if the exception is thrown or not action will be performed. Hope this helps.

Comment: Vinay, I am using ExpectedConditions class of WebDriver and code is taken from webdriver code. i can catch staleElementReference but there is no point if we are doing the same in Wrapper class which is specifically written to provide abstraction of functionality.My understanding of elementToBeClickable was it will no throw StaleElementReference Exception as the same is being caught in the catch block of the function .

Comment: Kapil, if my understanding is correct the above code you have mentioned is for verifying for the presence of and element. Is there a catch block for stale element in this method? If not then this is the method which is throwing stale element exception and not the clickable method.

Comment: As mentioned this code is copy of ExpectedConditions class you can check method "elementTobeClickable" over here . link for the code is:https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java

Comment: Kapil, you are correct. There is a catch block for staleElement. Not sure why this is not working. But I still feel since there is no staleElement catch block for findElement method in the same class, this is the method which is throwing stale element exception, I guess. Because before performing an action the element has to be identified and findelement method might not catch stale element exception. I could be wrong. Hopefully some one would be able to able to answer.

Comment: Just to add on the previous comment the reason I guess why this was designed in this manner is since Stale element does not actually mean element is not present it simply means element has changed and we should still be able to perform the required operation. To give this flexibility an exception is thrown instead of catching it.

Comment: Thanks Vinay,Glad you understood the problem ,see at top level there is catch statement to return null so there is no point in adding catch  statement to every downstream methods , I have updated the question as this is specific to elementTobeClickable(WebElement element). The code which i have shown in question should be in try block

Comment: StaleElementException does not mean the element has changed.  It indicates that the HTML has been reloaded (refresh or AJAX). The element may have changed but there is no guarantee it has done.

Comment: Hi Robbie, I understand what staleElementException does but question is something different

Comment: Sometimes I will see a StaleElementReferenceException in one browser where I would not see it in another browser.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the call to the ExpectedCondition  in a WebDriverWait that uses the FluentWait  ".ignoring" clause for the StaleElementException.   Then you can loop over the expected condition a finite number of times until giving up with a TimeoutException.

---

UPDATE:  I have learned a lot since I first answered this question.  As a TDD developer, now I know that unit testing a method that uses expected condition wrapped in a try-catch block is difficult and writing code like that is not recommended.   For example, try to unit test the .ignoring clause in a method using FluentWait using Mockito.  It's not easy at all.   Creating a method that temporarily changes the implicit wait, then does a driver.findElement and a check for clickability followed by reverting the implicit wait back to the default of "0", is a lot easier to create a unit test for.  Just 2 more cents.

I'm probably going to write a test project that shows examples of this stuff on Github (sometime during 2015).